# How to connect to the browser environment (for DOT libs)

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js

I want to integrate DOT into app based on React Native. There is a problem with a connection to the browser environment: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document`.
A few more details:

- The issues with the WebAssembly were solved using asm.js
- The issue that remains is the linking to the browser environment: `ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: document`.
  There were also problems with the environment for other coins but they have been successfully mocked with rn-nodeify.
  This is the list of Dot libraries required for the browser environment:

```
"@polkadot/api": "7.4.1",
"@polkadot/until-crypto": “8.3.2",
"@polkadot/x-randomvalues": “8.3.2",
```

What should I do?
Thank you!

Comment: The only references for `document` inside [`@polkadot/util`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common) (& `util-crypto/x-randomvalues`) is as part of the license header. The same applies to [`@polkadot/api`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/tree/master/packages). This is after a full search of the source. Which library specifically do you have issues with? (It sounds environmental)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you could tell me if you know other projects that successfully support DOT on react native?

Comment: Stylo, Ledger, PolkaWallet all immediately spring to mind.

Comment: I consulted some more people on this, and it does not seem to be an issue with Polkadot JS, as other projects have used the library successfully with React Native. Likely the issue is with your project, so you will need to provide more information if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Here is a link to one of the applications referenced using Polkadot JS just fine: https://github.com/stylo-app/stylo